# Encoding issue with apostrophe in query string parameter, yaml and i18n

Tags: ruby, sinatra, yaml, prawn, i18n-gem

I have a parameter with an apostrophe in the query string, escaped:

```
class_name=John%27s
```

My script processes it, and gives it to a YAML file for i18n:

```
title: "How to sign up for %1's %2 messages:" # %2 == 'John%27s'
```

but the output is: `John&#39;s`

Instead of: `John's`

I tried to unescape the query parameters before giving it to YAML, and tried many combinations of format for the YAML, like `!!escape` and `!!html`, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with `&apos;` instead of `%27` http://www.htmlentities.com/html/entities/

Comment: `But the output is: John&#39;s`  Where is that output shown?  A browser will display `John&#39;s` as `John's`.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: No it doesn't, can't use &apos; in a query string (as the '&' serves as a separator) and if I tried to escape &apos; (%26apos%3B) it just never interprets it :/

Comment: The output is a PDF, created with the prawn gem and viewed in a browser. If I don't use YAML, and the r18n-gem and directly use the parameter in the prawm template, it works.

Comment: What happens if you do this: require "uri";

str = "John%27s";
str = URI.unescape(str)

Comment: Still displays `John&#39;s`

Comment: Just got double `&#39;` :/  `John&#39;&#39;s`